# Converting a PFX certificate to a JKS gives "Duplicate extensions not allowed" exception

Tags: java, ssl, pfx, jks

When trying to convert the PFX certificate with keytool:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore SomeCert.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass SomePass -destkeystore SomeCert.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass SomePass
```

I get the following exception

```
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed
```

Also, when using jetty's PKCS12Import tool, [as described here](http://www.cb1inc.com/2007/04/30/converting-pfx-certificates-to-java-keystores/), I get the same exception.

The main cause is the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed
      at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.parseExtension(CertificateExtensions.java:96)
      at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.init(CertificateExtensions.java:70)
      at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.<init>(CertificateExtensions.java:60)
      at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:723)
      at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:152)
      ... 92 more
```

I'm using Windows 7, JDK 8u25_x64.

Any ideas why this duplicate extensions problem is happening, and how can it be solved? When I use the certificate through a browser (e.g. to access the WSDL file for some WS, through Firefox) it works O.K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out the way to convert from PFX to JKS.

Here's the procedure, for future reference:

Step 1. **convert the pfx to pem**

Step 1.1. the private key

```
openssl pkcs12 -in SomeFile.pfx -nocerts -out privatekey.pem
```

Step 1.2. the certificate

```
openssl pkcs12 -in SomeFile.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.pem
```

Step 2. **create a keystore**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -certfile certificate.pem -name "some name" -out keystore.p12
```

Step 3. **create a JKS keystore**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore JKS
```

For this OpenSSL needs to be installed, and Java to be added to PATH (so that keytool command is available).

If someone just needs to import to Java keystore a certificate with a private key, skip Step 1.